# Change localstorage on form submit from 0 to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have the following form here

```
{{> header}}

<div class="container">
  <form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post" class="competitionformlockdown">
    <h2>School Competition Form</h2>
    <p>
      <b>All fields with <span style="color: red">*</span> are required</b>
    </p>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        General Information
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="schoolName">
              School Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="schoolName" placeholder="Enter school name" value="{{competitions.schoolName}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6 date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <label for="competitionDate">
              Competition Date <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionDate" name="competitionDate" placeholder="Enter the date of competition" value="{{competitions.competitionDate}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTime">
              Time <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTime" name="competitionTime" placeholder="Enter the time of the competition (e.g. 8:00 AM)" value="{{competitions.competitionTime}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionVenue">
              Venue <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionVenue" name="competitionVenue" placeholder="Enter where the competition was held" value="{{competitions.competitionVenue}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalOfStudents">
              Total number of students in the program <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalOfStudents" name="competitionTotalOfStudents" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalOfStudents}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalParticipated">
              Total number of students that participated <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalParticipated" name="competitionTotalParticipated" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalParticipated}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalPersonnel">
              Total number of school personnel involved in the program <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalPersonnel" name="competitionTotalPersonnel" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalPersonnel}}" required>
          </div>
        </div><!-- row ends -->
      </div><!-- End of panel body -->
    </div><!-- School Information panel ends -->

    <!-- Judge 1 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 1
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Name" name="competitionJudge1Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Telephone" name="competitionJudge1Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Email" name="competitionJudge1Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- Judge 2 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 2
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Name" name="competitionJudge2Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Telephone" name="competitionJudge2Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Email" name="competitionJudge2Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- Judge 3 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 3
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Name" name="competitionJudge3Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Telephone" name="competitionJudge3Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Email" name="competitionJudge3Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- The following fields are hidden to users and should ONLY be visible and editable by a site admin-level user. -->
    {{#if user.admin}}
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Administrators Only
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Sent Required Photos? (currently {{competitions.competitionRequiredPhotos}})</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredPhotos" id="yesPhotosRadio" value="yes">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="yesPhotosRadio">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredPhotos" id="noPhotosRadio" value="no">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="noPhotosRadio">No</label>
        </div>

        <p>Sent Required Certifications? (currently {{competitions.competitionRequiredCertifications}})</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredCertifications" id="yesCertsRadio" value="yes">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="yesCertsRadio">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredCertifications" id="noCertsRadio" value="no">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="noCertsRadio">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
    <!-- End of fields hidden to user -->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

{{> footer}}
```

and my current JS code

`localStorage.setItem('competitionformlockdown', '0' || '1');`

```
if(localStorage.getItem('competitionformlockdown') == '1') {
  $(".competitionformlockdown input").prop('disabled', true);
  $(".competitionformlockdown input[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true)
}
```

I want the forms to load with the value of 0 then when the form is submitted the value switches to 1 and triggers the `competitionformlockdown` on load and persists.

The forms are loading as 0 but the value is not switching to 1 on submit.

I'm new to localstorage so this is all new to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a `script` tag which sets the value to zero on form load, and then after the submit you can return the script tag to set to 1.

Form load

```
<script>
  var currentvalue =  localStorage.getItem('competitionformlockdown') || '0';
  localStorage.setItem('competitionformlockdown', currentValue);
</script>
```

On submit

```
localStorage.setItem('competitionformlockdown', '1');
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sygn/sd3xL3tu/4/)

Comment: So `currentValue` will change to '1' on submit?

Comment: Updated the gist

Comment: I'm getting this `Uncaught TypeError: competitionformlockdown.addEventListener is not a function` error

Comment: The code I have is this https://gist.github.com/benbagley/bebbe005726b2551f1e774e6e092fe52

Comment: updated fiddle with getElementByClassName, so that it's also here not only on the gist

Comment: Ok updated the gist again, feel free to edit the gist :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164930/discussion-between-ztadic91-and-b-j-b).